Bringing the limit inside the integral with asymptotic equilvance?
I was working on a limit problem and I think I found the solution to it, but I am not sure that what I did is right.
I am working with the following sequence of functions
$$ f_{n}(x) = n\, e^{\frac1{n\sqrt x}}-n,$$
and I want to compute the limit
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)\,\mbox{d}x.$$
Since $\,e^t-1 \sim t\,$ as $\, t\to 0$, I can say that for all $x \in (0,1)$ 
$$n(e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}n}}-1)\sim \frac{n}{n\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (\mbox{as }n\to+\infty).$$ Can this pointwise convergence let me say that
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)\,\mbox{d}x=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \,\mbox{d}x   \qquad?$$

If the functions were bounded by an integrable function, then you could easily apply the dominated convergence theorem. However, your functions have a blow-up at $x=0$. Plugging into Wolfram Alpha, it looks like the functions $f_n$ aren't integrable and $\int_0^1 f_n(x)\mathrm{d} x = \infty$ for each $n$.

No. You cannot take the limit inside except for very particular cases (uniform convergence of the sequence, dominated convergence, etc.).
In this case the limit does not even make sense because the functions $f_n$ are not integrable.
If they were, then $e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}n}}$ would be too.
Nonetheless, using the change of variables $u=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ we get $$\int_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}n}}\,dx=\int_1^\infty \dfrac{2e^\frac{u}{n} }{u^3}\,du$$
which clearly diverges.

None of the $f_n$ are integrable, since $e^x -1\geq \frac12x^2$ implies that $f_n \geq \frac{1}{2nx}$, whose integrals diverge.
This is an important example of a sequence of functions that pointwise decrease to an integrable function (namely $1/\sqrt{x}$) but where the monotone convergence theorem doesn’t hold.

The individual functions $f_n$ are not integrable on the given interval (their integral diverges to $+\infty$ near 0), while the pointwise limit function is integrable with integral $2.$
